# Esri basemap render speed abnormally slow in Chrome

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps, chrome

***Summary of Issue:***

In my project, using the oceans basemap from Esri is very slow to render when zoomed in very close (for Chrome only). Topo is also slow at high zoom levels, but it is bearable in comparison to oceans.

Using Chromes developer tools to look at the Network timing for the tiles reveals some are waiting 400+ ms, but this is also the case for topo so that's not too helpful.

Profiling using the Timeline tool shows that painting takes considerably longer with the oceans basemap.

You can try it yourself quickly in the sandbox by replacing "topo" with "oceans": 
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_simple

***Question:***

Is there anything on my end that I can do to optimize this in Chrome?

Comment: Looks like a slow tile server from ESRI - the wait response from their server is high for each map tile request this lags the application/

Comment: i'm seeing much faster speed than that today.  are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @JohnGravois Yes, this is has been persistent since I initially posted this question.

Comment: hmm.  consistent on other computers/networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try what this example says. I was facing the same problem with chrome. 
Set navigationMode to css-transforms and force3DTransforms to true.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/mapconfig_force_css3.html

I had also tweaked this:

```
esriConfig.defaults.map.panDuration = 1; // time in milliseconds, default panDuration: 250

esriConfig.defaults.map.panRate = 1; // default panRate: 25
esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomDuration = 100; // default zoomDuration: 500
esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomRate = 1; // default zoomRate: 25
```

Comment: This improved rendering speed dramatically!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `navigationMode: 'classic'` to your map options. The API documentation for the option is [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#navigationmode). I have not experienced this myself but others have reported it as a successful fix for slow basemaps and "flashing" tiles in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @tmcgee. I didn't have any luck on my end either, however.